# Compiling I18N interface to properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization

I am trying to use the [JLibs I18N](http://jlibs.in/i18n/Internationalization.html) library. For the dependencies, I have added the JAR files (`i18n` and `i18n-apt`) to the Eclipse Build Path:

[image: Eclipse Build Path]

Next, I simply use the sample source code as posted on the website.

```
import jlibs.core.util.i18n.I18N;
import jlibs.core.util.i18n.Message;
import jlibs.core.util.i18n.ResourceBundle;

@ResourceBundle
public interface DBBundle{
    public static final DBBundle DB_BUNDLE = I18N.getImplementation(DBBundle.class);

    @Message("SQL Execution completed in {0} seconds with {1} errors")
    public String executionFinished(long seconds, int errorCount);

    @Message(key="SQLExecutionException", value="Encountered an exception while executing the following statement:\n{0}")
    public String executionException(String query);

    @Message("executing {0}")
    public String executing(String query);
}
```

So far I get no compiler errors, which is great.

Moving on in the tutorial, it says

> When you compile this interface with jlibs-core.jar in classpath, it will generate Bundle.properties which contains the messages

So I also put `jlibs-core` into the classpath of Eclipse (see screenshot above) and performed a rebuild. Unfortunately, no Bundle.properties file is created, which I checked with [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/): every file is from May or older:

[image: Search Everthing]

What else do I need to make Jlibs compile the I18N interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to enable annotation processing in Eclipse. See [instructions here](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/introToAPT.php).

Add `jlibs-i18-apt`, `jlibs-apt` and `jlibs-core` to the factory path and try.

If you are comfortable with maven you can download a [sample maven project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/326301/jlibs-test.zip). When you compile, you can see generated files in target/classes folder.